# password protect file in apache 2.4 .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I used to protect files in olders versions of apache with this code in the folder´s .htaccess file:

```
AuthUserFile  /home/folder/.htpasswds/.htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthType basic
<Files "wp-login.php">
  require user superadmin
</Files>
```

With my .htpasswd being like this:

```
admin:EBbqCq1YlLHSQ
superAdmin:PrlugFjcTaqlg
```

But my ISP updated apache and the code in my .htacess stop working and the whole site displayed error 500.

Im trying to protect wp-login.php of wordpress to add an aditional layer of protection in case of a brute force attack.

I have looked for a solution but I havent found a soluction yet.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ive found the solution

```
 <FilesMatch "wp-login.php">
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Secure Area"
 AuthUserFile "/home/example/.htpasswds/public_html/wp-admin/passwd"
 require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/prevent-unauthorized-wp-admin-wp-login-php-attempts